# Unable to read environment variables using System.getenv() in azure VM

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, environment-variables, azure-vm

I’m trying to read environment variables using System.getenv() in a Java Spring boot application. I can read any env variable in my local but when I deploy my application to azure VM, System.getenv() returns null. Can someone please help.

Sample code I’m using:

```java
public void printEnv(){
  System.out.println(System.getenv(“HOSTNAME”);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `HOSTNAME` is a valid environment variable set on the running VM? You can try printing `System.getenv()` (it returns a map of all environment variables) to see for the available variables

Comment: HOSTNAME got removed when I stopped my service in VM. I had to export again to get the value of env variable.